# Trigger a special mouse event while first mouse event is already triggering

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

Right now i have a mousedown event firing, meanwhile I would like to trigger my mousemove event as well. But doing:`this.capture = false;` will fire all the mouse event. All I want is mouse move event (specific event) to trigger while mouse down event trigger;

The way to think about is. I want event B to trigger while triggering event A (not any event)

I am think of multithreading. But i don't have enough information about multithreading to go ahead and do it. So if that is what needs to be done, could anyone please provide me with the a bit of coding for my reference? Thanks a lot for reading.

---

And i know what you guys are thinking: 
"Why don't you just call the mouse move event inside mousedown"
Well i tried doing so, but the mouseeventarg is not updating, in other words the mouse position for mouse move is still holding in a constant location since capture is still true in my case.

Comment: I think you are looking at Windows Messages wrong.  What exactly do you wish to accomplish?

Comment: All i want is I want two event to trigger together and separately

Comment: Why you don't try to trigger the B event in your A event handler?

Comment: if you read carefully again in my post you will see the reason why i choose not to

Comment: I think I might have understood your question. Are you moving the control when the mouse is moved, as if dragging the control?

Comment: I am trying to do a drag yes, but i don't want to use dragging event, so what I did instead i did a mouse down and a mouse move. Long story short, i just need to keep this code the same while there are alot more event inside my program. So please anyone can help me do a muliti event call?

Comment: I answered based on what I think is the problem. If you post some code than I can give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i did it is i use another timer to replace the mouse-move event, I simple use the global screen mouse position to location whatever i want to during the mouse down event, this can simulate a mouse drag action. As yes i perhaps should just use mouse drag instead at the beginning of my code. thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what is happening is that since you are moving the control, the mouse position relative to the control is constant and that's why mouseeventarg is not updating. On MouseDown you should save the initial position of the control, and when calling MouseMove you should add currentPosition.Left - initialPosition.Left to the mouse X, and .Top for Y.

When triggering the event, create a new MouseEventArgs object:

```
int newX = oldMea.X + Control.Left - initialPosition.Left;
int newY = oldMea.Y + Control.Top - initialPosition.Top;
var newMea = new MouseEventArgs(oldMea.Button, newX, newY, oldMea.Delta);
```

Comment: I know, i did save it. But the mouse move event is not updating at all.

Comment: AFAIK the MouseEventArgs are immutable so you need to create a new one to call the event.

Comment: Calling the event is not a problem. I mean how hard is to call the event, but like you said the mouse move event itself is fixed and don't know how to update itself since the mouse down event is triggering. Could you please provide me just a bit of code to get me started??